# a Catalan-type problem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

It is known that for every $n$ the equation $a^b-c^d=n$ has finite number of solutions (assuming that exponents are not 1's), but the proof requires a lot of hihger mathematics.

Is there an elementary proof that the particular case: $a^b-b^a=n$ has finite number of solutions?

Comment: Assuming $n\neq0$?

Comment: $n$ is a positive integer

Comment: Do you have a reference for your first claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *It is known that for every $n$ the equation $a^b-c^d=n$ has finite number of solutions 
>  $($assuming that exponents are not $1$'s$)$*

[No](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillai's_conjecture), it [isn't](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PillaisConjecture.html). Otherwise, it wouldn't be called a “[conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjecture)”. :-$)$

> *The proof requires a lot of higher mathematics.*

Yes. Of course it does. And the reason that we know that is because, if it wouldn't, then it'd already be proven. :-$)$

> *Is there an elementary proof that the particular case: $a^b-b^a=n$ has finite number of solutions?*

Take a wild guess$\ldots~$ :-$)$